# Matching integer within parentheses

Tags: ruby, regex

I tried the following:

```
(\([^0-9]*\d+[^0-9]*\))
```

on this:

```
Sales rank: 398 (was 644)
```

But I get this:

```
(was 644)
```

I only need the `644`

How can I fix my regex to accomplish that?

Comment: Could there be also something like `(was 644 (formerly 645))`, and if so, which number(s) would you want captured? Could there be something like `(was 644 or less)`, and would you still want to capture `644` in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
>> 'Sales rank: 398 (was 644)'[/\d+(?=\))/]
=> "644"
```

`(?=\))` was used to assert that the pattern is followed by closing paren. (*positive lookahead*)

**ALTERNATIVE**

```
>> 'Sales rank: 398 (was 644)'.scan(/\d+/)
=> ["398", "644"]
>> 'Sales rank: 398 (was 644)'.scan(/\d+/).last
=> "644"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can alternatively use this `regex` with @falsetru's answer

```
(?<=was )\d\d\d
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scan...

```
 >> 'Sales rank: 398 (was 644)'.scan(/\d+/)
 => ["398", "644"]
 >> 'Sales rank: 398 (was 644)'.scan(/\d+/).last
 => "644"
```

Thanks